# Can a single R/Markdown file contain all exercises for R/exams?

Tags: r-exams

Is it possible to have all exercises of an exam in the same R/Markdown file for R/exams? From what I have read, each question has to be in its own file. Sure, I can split, by using R, a R/Markdown file with several questions into files containing a single question, but wouldn't it be easier to have `exam2xyz` doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a fundamental design principle in R/exams that 1 exercise = 1 file (either .Rmd or .Rnw).

At first this might seem a bit overcomplicated, especially if you are used to putting together written exams with static exercises in a particular order. Users who do so often apply some manual randomization as they include small variations when they re-use exercises from old exams.

In contrast, R/exams is designed for a different workflow. The goal is to write exercises that already include some level of randomization so that they can be re-used without modification in different contexts, e.g., in different combinations of exercises in written exams or as one of many similar exercises in an item pool in a learning management system etc.

Therefore requiring that every exercise is a different file facilitates:

- Building a large pool of independent exercises.
- Working on the exercise pool collaboratively, e.g., in a version control system.
- Thorough stress testing of dynamic exercises to make sure that they work in many random variations.
- Re-using the same exercise file in different contexts.

If you feel that this does not suit your workflow well, that's fair enough. In that case I would choose some separator line between different exercises in the same file. Then you can write a small function creates files in a temporary directory with the split up files. Feel free to ask for feedback on this if you're struggling with that. But before you do I would encourage you to try to go along with the separate files.

Comment: Thanks again, Achim, for your always very helpful answers! In my case, the questions of an exam can not be partitioned, as they depend on the situation described in each exam. Suppose the situation of an exam is the quotation of a book and that one wants to ask questions about that quotation. Anyhow, I can write a function to split all questions into separated .Rmd files.